# Python scrapy, how to enable caching only for certain parts of websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping a website with scrapy, and I know that some of the pages with specific URLs will not change at all, ever, and other parts of the website with specific URLs change often. I am using  `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True` and would obviously only want to cache the pages that never change while pinging the server for pages that do change. How can I accomplish this, if I know the format of which URLs will change and which wont?

Comment: I found "HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_SCHEMES = [], Don’t cache responses with these URI schemes." in the settings documentation. Would this be what I want? I want to be able to set specific URLs that follow a pattern to ignore caching, maybe with regex. I am not quite sure what a URI scheme is. If this is what I want and someone can elaborate on this in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You have to provide a custom caching policy with the logic in `should_cache_request(self, request)` and then set the policy with `HTTPCACHE_POLICY = your policy object`